# Customized date format in kusto?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I would like to know if there is a possibility to customize the format of a specific datetime in KQL.

For example I have the following code:

let value = datetime(2022-06-08);
print Date = value

As a result I get: 2022-06-08 00:00:00

My question here is that instead of having 2022-06-08 00:00:00, is there a possibility to format it in a way to have the **Date = 8 June 2022**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the [supported formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/format-datetimefunction#supported-formats) you can do stuff like this:

```js
let dt = datetime(2017-01-29 09:00:05);
print 
v1=format_datetime(dt,'yy-MM-dd [HH:mm:ss]'), 
v2=format_datetime(dt, 'yyyy-M-dd [H:mm:ss]'),
v3=format_datetime(dt, 'yy-MM-dd [hh:mm:ss tt]')
```

However the month of year is supported only as numeric values in datetimes.

Maybe run [case()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/casefunction#example) in order to get June, July etc

```js
let GetMonth = view(Month:int){
case(
    Month==1, "January",
    Month==2, "February",
    Month==3, "March",
    Month==4, "April",
    Month==5, "May",
    Month==6, "June",
    Month==7, "July",
    Month==8, "August",
    Month==9, "September",
    Month==10, "October",
    Month==11, "November",
    Month==12, "December"
)};

let x = datetime(2017-01-29 09:00:05); 
let month = monthofyear(x);
print strcat(
  dayofmonth(x), " ", 
  GetMonth(monthofyear(x)), " ", 
  datetime_part("Year", x))
```

Comment: No need for `case`. You can use an array instead.